# Next.js sticky navbar issue wont stick after use of Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Using next.js, I'm having an issue in regards to the sticky navbar I made.  To summarize, it works properly on initial load of site, however, when I use a link on the bar and go to my next page, the navbar fails unless I click on the same Link twice.

A screencastify of the issue:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AIYXrjGP9_lAsQ32bhDzWPtTLQt-czTm/view

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Layout(props) {
  async function myFunction() {
    var contentBoxV =
      contentBox.getBoundingClientRect().top +
      document.documentElement.scrollTop +
      (content.getBoundingClientRect().top +
        document.documentElement.scrollTop) *
        0.25;

    var windowOffset =
      content.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    console.log(contentBoxV);
    console.log(windowOffset);

    if (contentBoxV >= windowOffset + 15) {
      navbar.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var content = document.getElementById("subNav");
    var contentBox = document.getElementById("contentH");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div
        id="contentH"
        className="container-xl contentDocument"
        onScroll={() => myFunction()}
      >
        <div className="iceBorder"></div>
        <div className="frostBack"></div>
        <div id="paddingTop"></div>
        <div id="subNav"></div>

        <div id="navbar" className="container navMenu fixedIntro">
          <div className="row linkContainer">
            <Link href="/">
              <div className="col navLink">Jeffrey Arriaga</div>
            </Link>

            <a
              id="resumePDF"
              className="col navLink"
              href="/ArriagaJeffrey_Resume_noPhone_CS_Version.pdf"
              target="_blank"
            >
              Resume
              <img id="pdfMiniCon" src="/29587.png" alt="pdfFileImg" />
            </a>

            <div className="col navLink">Portfolio</div>
            <Link href="/contact">
              <div className="col navLink">Contact</div>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>

        {props.children}

        <footer>
          <p>Jeffrey Arriaga</p>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's not common in reactjs to access a dom node via `getElementById`, please read the [docs  about refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)